# How to write a registry entry on uninstallation using wix

Tags: wix, registry, uninstallation

Is it possible to write to windows registry during uninstallation of an application? Is such functionality supported by Wix. I want to avoid doing it in an assembly and calling the function using custom actions. However, I would not mind creating an in-script custom action.

Regards,

Wamiq

Comment: Could you explain what you need to write? Perhaps there is a better way to achieve what you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

That's not supported by the Windows Installer. You will need a custom action of some sort. Remember rollback though!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its even possible on the Windows Installer level, still you can run a reg.exe on uninstall using the [quite execute custom action (QTExec)](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/qtexec.htm) which is build in in Wix.